# Disable/Reenable div event handlers using jQuery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-1.4

We are using a page with layers of Javascript tabs. We are trying to disable access to some of the tabs based on user permissions.

For example, here is a tab example:

```
<div class="executives tab productA productB productC" runat="server" id="executivesTop">
    <div class="tabLeft">
        <div class="tabMain">
            Executives
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "tabLeft" and "tabMain" are just for the CSS layout of the tabs and do not interfere with anything. The "executivesTop" div is where all of the action takes place. We use a separate .js file that assigns the event handlers to the various tabs.

When the page loads, I want to disable all mouseenter, mouseleave, mouseover, and click events on all tabs. I first did this with the following lines in (window).load:

```
//this line disables the event handlers from the tabs
$(".tab").unbind('mouseover mouseenter mouseleave click');
//this line changes the basic css to appear "disabled"
$(".tab").css('color', 'grey');
```

We have a server-side script that determines the current user's permissions and sends those to a field that jQuery can read. jQuery then looks at those permissions and enables tabs accordingly.

```
//SubscriptionsInput is a hidden label that has a list of user permissions in the form of "productA,productB,productC"
if (SubscriptionsInput.toLowerCase().indexOf("productA") >= 0) {
    $(".productA").bind('mouseover mouseenter mouseleave click');
}
```

Obviously this isn't going to work, as I'm not reassigning the event handlers to the tabs. The various mouse events go through a class sheet, and the click events are in the aforementioned .js file. I don't know how to reassign these. I think my reasoning is sound, though, in disabling everything and then reenabling things as permissions dictate.

The simple solution, as far as what I've researched suggests, is to use the .on() and .off() functionality, which would be great if we were at jq1.9 or better, but we're at jq1.4.2 still, which is frustrating. I can't use .bind()/.unbind() unless there is a simple way to reattach the event handlers from the existing .js file.

I really just need to be able to disable and reenable "mouse*" and "click" and can't use .on()/.off(). Also, I need to be able to revert the css of the tabs back to the stylesheet definitions.

I hope I've explained this clearly enough. Can anybody offer any suggestions or code tricks I could use to bring this functionality to life?

edit: my initial build had all the tabs loading and the ABSENCE of a permission would disable relevant tabs, which would make the .unbind() idea work well (as permissions wouldn't be given or removed mid-session so an unbind is fine), but some tabs are applicable to multiple permission levels. I'd rather enable content as users have permissions rather than risk disabling something that should be accessible at a given permissions level.

Comment: Do not "unbind" them if they don't need to be unbound. In other words, combine your unbind script with your enable script in such a way that instead of unbinding and then binding, just don't do either if it isn't needed.

Comment: I'm pretty green w/r/t js/jq, so "unbind()" was just something I saw in another stackoverflow post so I used it. It did the trick, but the re-binding is obviously the problem. I really just need to be able to disable "mouse*" and "click" and can't use .on()/.off().

Comment: My point is you can't re-do what you undid with .unbind without re-initializing the entire tabs widget. Therefore, it would be best to re-organize your logic to not unbind in the first place if it's a case where you would have needed to rebind it.

Comment: You do understand, none of this is actually keeping users from getting into the disabled tabs, right? Anyone can open the console and add a style attribute that shows the tab.

Comment: Well, the disabled tabs load a new page in an iframe through the click event. I was not aware that this is not keeping users out of the tabs, as disabling the click event means there's no handler to load the iframe.

Comment: Right, but what stops someone from simply adding the iframe themselves? the src of it is in the code. This stuff really should be handled server-side.

Comment: Well, technically nothing. If they wanna get into Firebug or whatever and change the source of the iframe, they can, but ASP.NET won't allow somebody to access a product they don't have permission for.

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic around to only unbind if they don't have permissions.

```
//this line disables the event handlers from the tabs
//$(".tab").unbind('mouseover mouseenter mouseleave click');
//this line changes the basic css to appear "disabled"
//$(".tab").css('color', 'grey');

//SubscriptionsInput is a hidden label that has a list of user permissions in the form of "productA,productB,productC"
if (SubscriptionsInput.toLowerCase().indexOf("productA") == 0) {
    $(".productA").unbind('mouseover mouseenter mouseleave click').css('color', 'grey');
}
```

Comment: That was my original implementation, but I realized that some tabs are accessible to multiple permissions and I may be inadvertently removing  access to a tab that somebody should have access to. There are workarounds of course, but I'm trying to make this solution as elegant as possible. I may have to just revert to this solution.

Comment: I can see how that's going to get complex, the if statements are going to be rather long